# Kafka broker constantly ISR shrinking and expanding?

Tags: apache-kafka

We have a cluster of 4 nodes in production. We observed that one of the
nodes ran into a situation where it constantly shrunk and expanded ISR for
more than 1 hours and unable to recover until the broker was bounced.

```
[2017-02-21 14:52:16,518] INFO Partition [skynet-large-stage,5] on broker 0: Shrinking ISR for partition [skynet-large-stage,5] from 2,0 to 0 (kafka.cluster.Partition)
[2017-02-21 14:52:16,543] INFO Partition [skynet-large-stage,37] on broker 0: Shrinking ISR for partition [skynet-large-stage,37] from 1,0 to 0 (kafka.cluster.Partition)
[2017-02-21 14:52:16,544] INFO Partition [skynet-large-stage,13] on broker 0: Shrinking ISR for partition [skynet-large-stage,13] from 1,0 to 0 (kafka.cluster.Partition)
[2017-02-21 14:52:16,545] INFO Partition [__consumer_offsets,46] on broker 0: Shrinking ISR for partition [__consumer_offsets,46] from 3,2,0 to 3,0 (kafka.cluster.Partition)
.
.
```

I'd like to know what would cause this issue and why the broken broker was not kicked out of ISR.

Kafka version is 0.10.1.0

Comment: Was there anything in the other nodes logs when this occurred? There are two reasons why a broker would shrink the ISR: 1. the replica cannot keep up with the data 2. the replica has tried to read anything for a while. So I would suspect that the issue is either with the other brokers or with connectivity between the nodes.
Once the replicas read up to the end of the partition they will be added to the ISR - this probably caused the "bouncing" you saw.
The broker was not dropped from the ISR because it was almost certainly the leader for this partition.

Comment: Did you find any exceptions like " Connection to ** was disconnected before the response was read". It looks like a Kafka known issue. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4477 for details.

Comment: @amethystic,Yes,i find the 'connection to..' exception. I will update the version of the kafka. Thank you.

Comment: @SönkeLiebau,Thank you.

Comment: @Baby.zhou Did version upgrade solved the problem for you ?

Comment: @KumarSambhav,`kafka_2.11-0.10.1.1`

Comment: We have 0.11.0.1 and had the same error, so I am kinda puzzled regarding the version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There was that bug in KAFKA-4477 that got fixed, but in general, I've seen this same problem when Kafka brokers time out when talking to a zookeeper node (default is 6000ms timeout), for some transient network blip, at which point they get kicked out of the cluster, partition leadership changes, clients have to rebalance, etc.  For high volume clusters, it's a pain.

Simply increasing this timeout has helped me several times before:

```
 zookeeper.session.timeout.ms
```

The default value according to the official docs is 6000ms. I found simply increasing it to 15000ms caused the cluster to be rock solid.

Documentation for 0.11.0 Kafka version: https://kafka.apache.org/0110/documentation.html